# 2 source system insert into same table at same time

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql server table with primary key column and a sequence column. I have 2 processes that are going to insert data into this table at the same time. Will this cause any kind of issue, like deadlock?

Please note that both the processes will never insert data with same primary key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A deadlock requires attempting to access two (or more) resources shared between two (or more) processes. If the issue is truly as simple as two processes issuing `insert` statements for a single table with no other secret activity, e.g. triggers, you won't have any issues.

Comment: @HABO, I too think that PK won't cause issue as long as the sources make sure to insert distinct PK. What about the sequence column? If both sources insert with commit after every 1000 inserts, then will the sequence column cause any issue?

Comment: Either an `identity` column or a column with a default value from a `sequence` will be fine.